# Geographic subdivisions with Geocoder

Tags: android, google-maps, google-geocoder

I use Geocoder to get an address from a part of string like this:

```
Address[addressLines=[0:"36 Avenue des Champs-Élysées",1:"75008 Paris",2:"France"],feature=36,admin=null,sub-admin=null,locality=Paris,thoroughfare=Avenue des Champs-Élysées,postalCode=75008,countryCode=FR,countryName=France,hasLatitude=true,latitude=48.8700213,hasLongitude=true,longitude=2.3080506,phone=null,url=null,extras=null]
```

with this code (address is my part of string):

```
try {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(c, Locale.FRENCH);
        addresss = geocoder.getFromLocationName(address, 3);



    } catch (Exception e) {}
```

With this address I can have the city (Address.locality) the country (Address.country), but not areas between city and country. 
I don't know how countries are subdivised everywhere in the world, but for example, in France, you have the 36000 cities like "Paris", in 102 departments ("Paris" is in department "Paris" (the same name)), themselves in 22 regions ("Paris" in region "Ile de France"). Equivalent of regions in USA has to be State or maybe a subdivision of State...
I don't see how to obtain these informations with Adress. Do you know how to do that?

Thank's by advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the android app does not provided that. But you can get it with [the web api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#GeocodingResponses). They return a much detailed type then the android app, also look at this [Address Types and Address Component Types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Types) section

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have just found 5 minutes ago, and now, your answer goes in the same way, pretty cool! So I think I'll use GeoCoder in real time address and confirm with web api when i want to write on a database! But I wonder, is all well subdivided or can we have adress with no answer? I mean, do I have to prevent null results for subdivisions?

Comment: I think I saw empty respond in some of the fileds. (for a Japanese address? I don't remember)

Comment: Lol, it's understandable: Japan is a sismic country...Location always moving ^^ (joke). Thank you for answers, i'll prevent null response so!